# How to get pdf as a file in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, pdf, react-pdf

I want to get it as a format as we upload a file. The pdf file stored on the client site. I don't want to use the upload method also not get the file from the backend.

```
lastModified: 1619065221844
lastModifiedDate: Thu Apr 22 2021 10:20:21 GMT+0600 (Bangladesh Standard Time) {}
name: "DE High School Analysis Questionnaire.pdf"
size: 1636916
type: "application/pdf"
webkitRelativePath: ""
```

Comment: Its not clear on what you are trying to do. 1) The client has a pdf file. 2) There is metadata associated with that pdf file. From there, what are you trying to achieve? Hint, the title doesn’t match your explanation.

Comment: Sorry, I want to view pdf file and get those files from react client side.

Comment: Do you have any solution?

Comment: Not clear at all.  In plain words, tell us what you are trying to do?  hint, trying to get a user to upload a pdf file without using "the upload method" is really a bad requirement.  Your write up makes no sense at all.  And apologies.. I'm sure its a 'lost in translation to english' issue.  No offense intended here..

Comment: I am sorry. Forget other comments. I just want to view pdf files in react.

Comment: have you seen this package?   https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-pdf